# How to dynamically set type hinting for inherited classes constructor?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

With the following code:

```
import dataclasses
@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int
    b: float
A(<cursor location>
```

If I now let my LSP pyright driver give me suggestions at the cursor location it finds "a" and "b" arguments.

[image]

How do I do that with my own class? Consider the following:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
       # This is done.
       for k, v in kvargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    def __init_subclass(cls) -> None:
       # How to add a and b typing information to A.__init__ ?
       print(get_type_hints(cls))
       setattr(cls, "__init__", 
            # magic? how to do this:
            def __init__(a: int, b: int): # how to generate function signature from get_type_hints ?
                super().__init__(a=a, b=b)
       )

class A(Parent):
    a: int
    b: float

A(<cursor location
```

I am not asking how to get the typing information from the class dynamically. Let's assume I want to exactly add `a: int, b: float` function as `A.__init__`, however the types are dynamic. I am asking how to set the type hints of a constructor dynamically from `get_type_hints` extracted from another type.

> Is this question about better autocompletion or how to generate a method dynamically?

About autocompletion and typing information. I have written my own `__init__` function that takes `*args, **kvargs` arguments and checks them manually. Now I want to have autocompletion and add `__annotations__` information to it. I tried to browse `dataclass` source code, however this is magic that I am not able to comprehend https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/dataclasses.py#L471 .

Comment: Is this question about better autocompletion or how to generate a method dynamically? If it's former, does [`@dataclass_transforms()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.dataclass_transform) work for you?

Comment: About autocompletion. Edited the question to add that information Thank you, `@dataclass_transforms()` looks very interesting either way, I did not know it exited.

Answer (score 0):

`typing` has native support for this: `dataclass_transform`. Using it is remarkably easy:

```py
from typing import dataclass_transform

@dataclass_transform()  # This must be called.
class Parent:
    ...
```

And that's it! Depending on how your parent class behave, you can provide corresponding keyword arguments, but the code above will work just fine on its own:

[image: Child(a: int, b: float) -> None]